# angularjs-nvd3-directives setting color in legend as well as in chart elements

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js

Good morning

I am using the angularjs-nvd3-directives, which is great, but I am having difficulties when setting the color of a multi bar chart (http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/multi.bar.chart.html).

The show legend works well:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
    <nvd3-multi-bar-chart
        data="exampleData"
        id="showLegendExample"
        width="550"
        height="300"
        showXAxis="true"
        showYAxis="true"
        xAxisTickFormat="xAxisTickFormatFunction()"
        showLegend="true">
            <svg></svg>
    </nvd3-multi-bar-chart>
</div>
```

But when I add this option in conjunction with `color="colorFunction()"` where,

```
var colorArray = ['#FF0000', '#0000FF', '#FFFF00', '#00FFFF'];
$scope.colorFunction = function() {
    return function(d, i) {
        return colorArray[i];
    };
}
```

The color of the chart objects updates, but not legend. Is this a limitation of angularjs-nvd3-directives, that I can either set the color or have a legend and not both, or am I missing something?

Comment: What happens if you directly use `color="['#FF0000', '#0000FF', '#FFFF00', '#00FFFF']"` instead of calling the funciton ?

Comment: adding this next to `<nvd3-multi-bar-chart` also causes the graph objects color to update, but not the legend colors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular NVD3 Change Colors In Legends Also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415490/angular-nvd3-change-colors-in-legends-also)

Comment: I have found the answer via a duplicate - see above: `legendColor="colorFunction()"`